# Meaning of 'pate' in 'una nave che pate tempesta'

Tags: meaning

I've come across the following phrase in a sixteenth century Italian book:

> Una nave che pate tempesta in un mar tanto orribile

I'm struggling with the meaning of 'pate'. Does anybody know the English or modern Italian equivalent?

Comment: I think it might mean 'endure', from the Latin 'patior', but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an alternative (but archaic) form of *patisce*. Verbs in the third conjugation oscillate between

- -isc-e
- -e

(not only in the third person singular, but in all the singular forms and in the third person plural).

For instance *l'acqua bolle* (water is boiling), but *la partita finisce alle sei* (the game ends at six).

For the verb *patire*, the modern usage follows the -*isc*- pattern:

> patisco, patisci, patisce, patiamo, patite, patiscono

but I'm not surprised seeing it was used with the other pattern like

> cucio, cuci, cuce, cuciamo, cucite, cuciono

(*cucire*, to sew). So *pate* is just the same as *patisce* (endures).

See the [entry in Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbi_incoativi) for more information; there is a long list of verbs that follow the *-isc*- pattern, with also alternative forms. For *patire* the non -*isc*- form are marked as archaic.

For the verb *divertire* the -*isc*- forms are considered archaic. So, how to choose one or the other? I'm afraid there is no hard and fast rule.

Answer (score 0):

In everyday language "pate" is not used anymore, so don't use it if you have to speak Italian, really. I'm Italian and when I read your question I said "wtf??" :.) This is a poem, I think, and it means "**a boat which suffers** (*but 'in the middle' is much better*) **of a storm**"!